how do i straighten these mesh edges?
I am currently starting a personal modeling project and I've noticed that my current mesh for the handle could be a bit neater for in the future when i do the UV handling work. Is there any techniques i can use to make it look nicer?


The shape of the handle is not straight, so why and in which way do you want to straighten the edges?
